# SELECT SINGLE vs SELECT UP TO 1 ROWS ENDSELECT correctness in HANA?

Tags: abap, hana, opensql

We are moving to HANA, and an external company is doing our code remediation. Some of it is automated. I see where this code change was made:

```
*{   REPLACE        DEVK9A1ZZH
*  SELECT SINGLE maktx
*                INTO tab-maktx
*                FROM makt
*                WHERE matnr EQ strmatnr
*                AND   spras EQ sy-langu.
  SELECT maktx
    UP TO 1 ROWS
    INTO tab-maktx
    FROM makt
    WHERE matnr = strmatnr
    AND   spras = sy-langu ORDER BY maktx.
  ENDSELECT.
```

I thought `SELECT SINGLE` was always preferable to `SELECT...UP TO 1 ROWS...ENDSELECT.` and that `ORDER BY` doesn't do anything when only one record is obtained. It seems that they're replacing every `SELECT SINGLE` in our code. What in my coworker's original code is not HANA compliant?

Comment: Not sure on the difference between `SINGLE` vs `UP TO` keywords, but the `ORDER BY` says "If you have more than one record returned by this WHERE clause, then order by this one field and grab the top 1 record" I would say that is VERY important to `SINGLE` or `UP TO` query, unless you are very positive that only one record is returned before the `UP TO`/`SINGLE` is applied to the record set. Otherwise you'll just pick up some random `maktx` from the intermediate result (before the `UP TO` is applied).

Comment: @JNevill, MATNR and SPRAS are the key fields of MAKT, so always one line is returned. More generally, ORDER BY might or might not be useful depending on your business needs. Quite often any value is fine, for example in existance checks.

Comment: @JNevill you bring up a very good point in that `UP TO...ORDER BY` will guarantee that the first `maktx` record is obtained. I agree with @András that this really shouldn't matter *in this particular case* since the selection is already performed using all of the key fields.

Comment: @András I totally agree. Because we are selecting against the key the ORDER BY is superfluous, furthermore so is the `SINGLE`/`UP TO` but probably necessary by the compiler to insure that only a scalar result is returned. I don't write enough abap to know it it would balk should that be omitted. I'm just speaking from a RDBMS context where the `SINGLE`/`UP TO` and `ORDER BY` are there because: "Better safe than sorry" and "Future proofing" for the next ding dong that comes along and changes the WHERE condition to not select against the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urban legend (and my experience, but I cannot prove it) say common DBMS provide the rows using the primary key, just because that is the way they keep the data stored. HANA sorts by columns and not by rows, so when you ask just for a single row, it returns to you with the first row "she" can manage to build with your conditions.

As you cannot do a `SELECT SINGLE...ORDER BY`, you must find an alternate way:

- recommended: fulfill the `WHERE` clause with enough conditions to get the row you really need
- ask HANA to simulate the old DBMS behavior by asking "just a single row, seeking by primary key"

If you manage to always provide a `WHERE` clause with enough conditions, you can continue with the SINGLE syntax, but I fear some companies will ask you to NOT do it, because they faced the results of lazy coders who relied on the old DMBS behavior :(

Comment: "Common DBMS provide the rows using the primary key, just because that is the way they keep the data stored. HANA sorts by columns and not by rows, so when you ask just for a single row, it returns to you with the first row "she" can manage to build with your conditions." This whole statement is simply not true. "Return data via primary key" seems to be one of the "urban legends" of databases...

Comment: Added "the urban legend intro", as I cannot prove my assumption with facts. It's just the way DBMS always gave me data :(

Answer (score 2):

## Sometimes it is necessary, mostly not

Mostly it is not necessary, just like in your example.

`SELECT SINGLE`s can be categorized in 3 groups:

- Full primary key searches
- Existence checks
- Other

## Full primary key searches

`matnr` and `spras` are the primary key fields of table `makt`, so the same row is already returned, independently from any ordering.
I guess the third party tool is not sophisticated enough to check the key fields of the selected table.

### Existence checks

Quite a lot of SELECT SINGLEs are used just to check if a values exists in the DB.

```
SELECT SINGLE posnr
    FROM VBPA 
    WHERE vbeln = iv_vbeln
```

We don't care which item number is returned, just if it is greater than 0. The conversion here is also unnecessary, the ordering does not matter.

## When is it useful?

Only in the third case, when we do not have the full primary key, but we still care about ordering. This is quite rare.

Checking for primary key is hard, and it is downright impossible to find out if the original programmer needed a specific order from code.

### This tool will give you more false positives than useful findings.

Comment: Got it, that's pretty much what we determined. This form of mass-changing is really only useful for correcting cases where the DBMS ordering by row was depended on but now is not (as it is column-sorted). It seems that the field they choose to sort over is arbitrary (in my example, not a key field, but what was being selected). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine either way (but far more efficiently coded in the first, unremediated version), because you're issuing the primary key of MAKTX (MATNR + SPRAS), and thus only one record can be returned and order is irrelevant.

HANA auto-remediations usually seem to do a lot of unnecessary "fixes" but that one is particularly annoying.